# Can the public status of Mi Yodeya be revoked?

Tags: discussion, launch

Does this site need to continuously meet any sort of metrics or threshold in order to remain public?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are three kinds of sites:

1. private beta
2. public beta
3. graduated / launched

This site has officially launched (party coming soon). Sites don't go backwards... once they are public, they stay public; once they graduate, they stay graduated.

In a few circumstances we closed sites due to complete lack of activity. We only close sites if we feel like almost no questions are getting good answers and the site itself is an "attractive nuisance" on the internet. The sites we closed were extreme ghost towns compared to this site so it seems extremely unlikely that mi.yodeya will ever get closed down.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what were those sites?

Comment: See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/04/when-a-site-grows-quiet/

Comment: ["Maalin bakodesh vein moridin."](http://lookstein.org/lookjed/read.php?1,4510,4552)

Comment: The sites that were closed were in beta; they never made it to launch.

Comment: Right. No launched site has ever been closed. We spend a lot of time and money on the graphic design for a site, so we don't do that if we aren't confident that the site is going to be around for a long time.